# How to make only selected radio button value change tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, radio-button

I have four radio buttons and 4 values. I want it so that when a selected radio button is chosen that the value will change from the value entered in the entry box but only for that radio button selected, while the rest stay the same to what they were perviously.

Currently in my code all the values change to the value entered in the entry box.

```
from tkinter import*

class NumberValues:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

class NumberGUI:
    def __init__(self, parent):

        self.numbers = [NumberValues(4000), NumberValues(4000), NumberValues(8000), NumberValues(8000)]

        i_value = 0 #value given to radiobutton

        #set up for show radio buttons
        self.numChoice = IntVar() #instance for IntVar created
        self.numChoice.set(0) #sets the initial selection

        self.NumberList = []

        for num in self.numbers: #for loop outputs show info
            self.show_rb = Radiobutton(parent, variable = self.numChoice, value = i_value)
            self.show_rb.grid(row = i_value, column = 0)

            self.num_label = Label(parent, text = int(num.value))
            self.num_label.grid(row = i_value, column = 1)

            self.NumberList.append(self.num_label)

            i_value += 1

        self.quantity_entry = Entry(parent, width = 15)
        self.quantity_entry.grid(row = i_value + 1, column = 0)

        self.confirmOrder_btn = Button(parent, text = "Enter Number", command = self.calculate_num) 
        self.confirmOrder_btn.grid(row = i_value + 1, column = 1)


    def calculate_num(self):

        showNumberList = []

        placement = int(self.numChoice.get())

        for i in range(len(self.numbers)):
            number = int(self.quantity_entry.get())
            self.numbers[i].value = self.numbers[i].value - number
            avaiable = int(self.numbers[i].value)
            showNumberList.append(avaiable)
            self.NumberList[i].configure(text = showNumberList[i])

# main routine
if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()
    numberCaluclating = NumberGUI(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

As shown i have created a placement variable that indicates the place of the value that should be changing in my list. I thought of using this in someway but what i have tried still changes them all to the incorrect value.

Lists are not needed in this, i just thought it was a possible way to keep all the values together and configure them together.

So how do i make it that when a selected radio button is chosen that only that value changes and the other values change when their radio button is selected?

Comment: One way would be to check the status of the radio buttons once a number is entered, and only update the corresponding label. But in order to do that, you need to keep references to the radio buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look - I've removed some of your logic but the GUI updates as required:

```
from tkinter import*

class NumberValues:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

class NumberGUI:
    def __init__(self, parent):

        self.numbers = [NumberValues(4000), NumberValues(4000), NumberValues(8000), NumberValues(8000)]

        i_value = 0 #value given to radiobutton

        #set up for show radio buttons
        self.numChoice = IntVar() #instance for IntVar created
        self.numChoice.set(0) #sets the initial selection

        self.NumberList = []

        self.link = [] ###

        for num in self.numbers: #for loop outputs show info
            self.show_rb = Radiobutton(parent, variable = self.numChoice, value = i_value)
            self.show_rb.grid(row = i_value, column = 0)

            self.num_label = Label(parent, text = int(num.value))
            self.num_label.grid(row = i_value, column = 1)

            self.NumberList.append(self.num_label)

            self.link.append( (self.show_rb, self.num_label) ) ###

            i_value += 1

        self.quantity_entry = Entry(parent, width = 15)
        self.quantity_entry.grid(row = i_value + 1, column = 0)

        self.confirmOrder_btn = Button(parent, text = "Enter Number", command = self.calculate_num)
        self.confirmOrder_btn.grid(row = i_value + 1, column = 1)


    def calculate_num(self):
        placement = int(self.numChoice.get())
        ###
        self.link[placement][1].configure(text = int(self.quantity_entry.get()) )

# main routine
if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()
    numberCaluclating = NumberGUI(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: In contrast to my comment to the question, the selection (radio button) is already available as `placement` so that can be used as index to access the corresponding Label (which I keep reference to in `self.link`.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be asking how to set just one value instead of all values. Unless I misunderstand the question, all you need to do is remove the loop.

For example:

```
def calculate_num(self):

    index = int(self.numChoice.get())
    number = int(self.quantity_entry.get())
    new_value = self.numbers[index].value - number
    self.numbers[index].value = new_value
    self.NumberList[index].configure(text=new_value)
```